# PHP cURL, file_get_contents blank page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a page content with cURL or file_get_content. On many websites it's working but i'm trying to do that on a friend's server and it's not.

I think there is a protection with header or things like that. I get the following error code : 401 forbidden. If i try to reach the same page with a normal browser it works.

Here is my code for the file_get_contents function :

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://192.168.1.3');

echo $homepage; // just a test to see if the page is loaded, it's not.

if (preg_match("/my regex/", $homepage)) {
   // ... some code
}
```

I also tryed with cURL :

```
$url = urlencode('http://192.168.1.3');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0');
$result = curl_exec($ch) or die("Not working"); 
curl_close($ch);

echo $result; // not working ..
```

Nothing works, maybe i should add more args to curl_setopt ...

Thanks.

PS : If i try with linux (wget) i get an error, but if i try with aria2c it's working.

Comment: I'd just ask my friend.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure you can access `192.168.1.3`? `192.168.1.3` is an **internal IP** and requires you to be on the same network (and most likely the same subnet, so your own IP would most likely have to start with `192.168.1.X` - **and** be on the same network - this will **not** work over the internet unless you use a VPN). What happens with `telnet 192.168.1.3 80`?

Comment: `401` is `unauthorized` `403` is `forbiden` can you please Re-Check the error ?
is that router or device ?

Comment: if you really have 401 forbiden that means that not allow remote view of this only from `192.168.1.3` can view the page

Comment: With a normal browser i can access it normally. (firefox, chrome ...).
As soon as i try to get it in php it's not working and i get 401 error ...

Comment: ok it sounds like you have to set useragent and accept-cookies

Answer (score 0):

try this update with useragent

```
<?php
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.3/');
curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$homepage = curl_exec($curlSession);
curl_close($curlSession);
echo $homepage ;
?>
```

if still getting blank page you have to install this [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/httpfox/) on firefox and see the "request-headers" and "response-headers"
[image]

Comment: Still getting a blank page. I tryed on an other web site it worked but on my friend's one it's still not working

Comment: @Maxime if you tell me more about the 192.168.1.3 what is i could help you

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status 401 means that UNAUTHORIZED. You need send the server with username and passwd。

With file_get_contents, you add the second param . That's a context-steam, which you can set header info.

You'd better to use curl for file_get_contents intend to access local file, as it's a block function.  Add the option as following, it's a basic authorize.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"my_username:my_password");
```

Comment: 403 forbiden and 401 unauthorized it is not the same the user has sad that 401 forbiden

Comment: 401 Forbidden is the HTTP status code produced by a web server when you are not allowed to access the page or file you have asked for. For instance, if the page is password-protected and you don't know the password, you might see a 401 Forbidden error. Some websites are locked down so that only those on the local company or school network can access parts of the site. You will also see 401 Forbidden errors in these cases.

Comment: Sometimes webmasters try to set up dynamic web programming features like PHP or Perl/CGI but fail to do so correctly. This can also result in 401 Forbidden errors until the web server is correctly configured.

401 Forbidden can appear in other situations at the discretion of the webmaster, so you may see it in scenarios other than these.